# What is the behaviour of callback execution in C# (assuming configure await is not set to false and assuming there is synchronization context)?

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

In Javascript, the callback (of the awaited async function) runs only when the call stack is empty. If there are multiple callbacks, then they are queued (in the event loop queue) such that only 1 callback runs in its entirety before the next callback gets change to run.

In case of C# (assuming ConfigureAwait is not set to false - that is - the callabck will run in the same thread; also assuming there is syncronization context [winforms]):

1. Does the callback run immediately without waiting for call stack to be empty?
2. Suppose there are multiple callbacks queued, then while 1 callback is running, and another callback is ready for execution, then does the running callback suspend while the new callback wants to run? Or is it sequential?

Comment: What stack? There's a lot of context here that's missing - it would help if you'd provide a complete, concrete example in C# and then ask very specific questions. (I *suspect* the answer to all of these will be "it depends on the synchronization context of the awaiting code" but it's hard to know for sure.)

Comment: I guess with stack OP meant event loop queue.

Comment: I have added some more context to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it depends on the current `SynchronizationContext` and, if that is `null`, the current `TaskScheduler`.

When the `await`ed `Task` completes, and you have configured the `Awaitable` to capture the context and recover on it, then almost certainly that continuation cannot continue immediately (the thread is likely busy executing something else). All that can be done is to schedule the continuation for later execution on the current `SynchronizationContext`, which is done by calling `SynchronizationContext.Post()`.

How this `Post` method is implemented depends on the `SynchronizationContext` (which is `abstract`). If you are using WPF, the `SynchronizationContext` is a `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`. There, `Post` is implemented by a call to `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` with `DispatcherPriority.Normal`.

In other words, your continuation gets queued on the dispatcher for later execution with normal priority. Other delegates may have higher priority (e.g. `DispatcherPriority.Input`), but eventually your delegate gets executed on the dispatcher.

Two things to notice:

1. `BeginInvoke` simply queues your delegate. It does not execute it right away. In other words, queuing your delegate is really fast.
2. The above explanation should illustrate why async-await is just syntactic sugar. You could achieve all these calls yourself, but the compiler does it for you, making your code flow more naturally.